# HTML5 - Canvas Element & Custom Cursor

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

HTML5 document - Canvas Element is not running the JavaScript parameters for the customized 'rectangle' cursor.  HELP PLEASE :)

```
    <head>
        <title>Canvas Element & Custom Cursor</title>
    </head>
    <body id="body" style="background-color:red;">

<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400" style="background- 
color:white;"> </canvas>

<script>
funtion CanvasProperties(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
canvas = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
window.addEventListener("mousemove", CustomCursor, false);}

function CustomCursor(){
canvas.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
var xPosition = clientX;
var yPosition = clientY;
canvas.fillRect(xPosition, yPosition, 100, 100);}

window.addEventListener("load", CanvasProperties, false);
</script>

    </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here, some already pointed out in Scimonster's answer, but an important one remains.

For the rectangle to be placed correctly you need to "correct" the mouse positions. The mouse positions are relative to client window while you will need them relative to canvas element.

Also, you are overriding canvas with context. Use a separate variable for it, and place those in global (parent) scope.

Here is a full version (inside the script tags):

```js
var canvas, context;                                   // place this in global scope
    
function CanvasProperties(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");        
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");                 // separate var for context...
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", CustomCursor, false);
}
    
function CustomCursor(e){
    var canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();   // get position of canvas element
    var xPosition = e.clientX - canvasRect.left;       // adjust mouse positions to
    var yPosition = e.clientY - canvasRect.top;        // become relative to canvas
    
    context.clearRect(0,0,600,400);                    // use context
    context.fillRect(xPosition - 50, yPosition - 50, 100, 100);
}
    
window.addEventListener("load", CanvasProperties, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Aha, when i tested it, the canvas was in the top left, so the mouse offset in the window and canvas was essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks for the post, Ken!  The clientX and clientY wouldn't work since the event property wasn't declared.  This is what I tried for my functions:

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `event` object at all -- `clientX` and `clientY` aren't global properties.

```
function CustomCursor(event){
canvas.clearRect(0,0,600,400);
var xPosition = event.clientX;
var yPosition = event.clientY;
canvas.fillRect(xPosition, yPosition, 100, 100);}
```

Comment: Scimonster, thanks for the post.  The "event" property still didn't fix the document.  After adding "event" property to CustomCursor (event), the HTML document still won't load the rectangle :( on the canvas element.

Comment: You have a typo at the beginning of the script -- `funtion` instead of `function`. Also, `canvas` isn't defined in the second function (`CustomCursor`), so i recommend removing the `var` statement in the first one, to make it global.

Comment: Thanks, Scimonster!  I am still unable to display the rectangle for the cursor in the canvas.  I appreciate your help though.

Comment: I got it to work with those 3 fixes. Do you want to create a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys!  We now have a custom cursor for painting on canvas :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Canvas Element & Custom Cursor</title>
    </head>

<body id="body" style="background-color:red;">

<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400" style="background- 
color:white;"> </canvas>

<script>
var canvas; var context;

function CanvasProperties(){
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
context = canvas.getContext("2d");
window.addEventListener("mousemove", CustomCursor, false);}

function CustomCursor(event){
var xPosition = event.clientX;
var yPosition = event.clientY;
context.fillRect(xPosition, yPosition, 100, 100);}

window.addEventListener("load", CanvasProperties, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```